# Align table header

Tags: tables, cals

I am trying to align the headers Setting 1 and Setting 2 as headers for Wins and Best score columns. However it is not working, I think is because the expanding commands are not correctly used. I will appreciate your help to fix this problem. This is my code :

```
\begin{calstable}[c]  % Centred CALS tabular

% Calculate the column width
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}            
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}}

% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 4

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.3pt}   % Outside horizontal frame rules
\def\cals@framecs@width{0,3pt}   % Outside vertical frame rules
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.3pt}    % Rule between header and tabular body
\def\cals@cs@width{0.3pt}        % Inside vertical rules
\def\cals@rs@width{0.3pt}        % Inside horizontal rules
\def\cals@bgcolor{}              % To avoid undefined

\def\gray{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    \def\cals@bgcolor{gray!30}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}

% R1H1     % Just a comment: Row one, header row one
\thead{
\brow
    \gray\alignC\nc{lrt}    % Switch to gray background and centred text, works until switched off
    \cell{\vfil}    
    \nc{rtb}\sc{Setting 1}
    \nc{tb}\sc{\vfil Setting 2}    
\erow
%R2H2       % Row two, header row two
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Game set}  % "vfil" centres the cell content vertically
    \cell{\vfil Wins}
    \cell{\vfil Best score}
    \cell{\vfil Wins}
    \cell{\vfil Best score}\gray % Always reset colour at end of header 
\erow
}  % closing 'thead' clause


%R3B1     % Row three, body row one
\brow
    \gray\cell{1}\gray   % Switch to gray background for first cell (column 1)
    \cell{\vfil 13.00}
    \cell{\vfil 13.00}
    \cell{\vfil 13.00}    
    \cell{\vfil 9.12}
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{2}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{3}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{4}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{5}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R3B1     % Row three, body row one
\brow
    \gray\cell{6}\gray   % Switch to gray background for first cell (column 1)
    \cell{\vfil 13.00}
    \cell{\vfil 13.00}
    \cell{\vfil 13.00}    
    \cell{\vfil 9.12}
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{7}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{8}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{9}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%R4B2
\brow
    \gray\cell{10}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow
%TOTAL
\brow
    \gray\cell{TOTAL}\gray
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}
    \cell{\vfil 11.89}    
    \cell{\vfil 10.45}        
\erow

\makeatletter
\end{calstable}
```

Comment: Hi, a chunk of code that cannot be compiled as is, in best cases it will need  annoying extra work just to make it compilable and test the result,   that however could be different to what you see with different document settings,  and in worse cases could be of not help at all,  because    it could be hard/impossible to guess the packages and setting to make to work this chunk of code as you expected.  Please, take your time to understand what is [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and why you should post a MWE, not a chunk of code.

Comment: I copied-pasted the code, it doesn't compile. An MWE is needed. However, I can notice at least: 1) does the environment support "[c]"? 2) 5 columns are expected, but the first row defines only 4 cells 3) Likely you need "\vfill" instead of just "\vfil".